# Piece of chess engine, which accomplishes move generation

Tags: c, chess

This is a piece of a chess - engine which accomplishes the generation of all (yet unvalidated) moves given a legal board. However, I have the strong doubt this is well written.
The following action are not yet included:

1. Promoting
2. Castling
3. En passant.

This code:

```
#include "chess.h"
#include "odinutilities.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 * Stores all moves given a pawns position,the pawns color, and a valid board position in move_info
 * Returns 0 if failed, otherwise 1. If a error occured, some valid moves might still be stored.
 * e.p not added yet.  
 */
char store_all_moves_of_pawn(char copy_board[8][8], char from_x, char from_y,
        MOVE_DATA* move_info, char color) {
    const char dy = (color + 1) ? 1 : -1;
    const char to_y = from_y + dy;
    for (char m = -1; m < 2; m++) {
        const char to_x = from_x + m;
        if ((to_x < 0) | (to_x > 7)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (m != 0) {
            //check if pawn can take left and right
            if (((to_y >= 0) & (to_y <= 7)) & (to_x >= 0) & (to_x <= 7)
                    & ((copy_board[(int) to_y][(int) to_x] * color) < 0)) {
                add_move_to_data(move_info,
                        create_move_string(from_x, from_y, to_x, to_y,
                                (char) 0));
            }

        } else {
            //can pawn move forward
            if (copy_board[(int) to_y][(int) to_x] == 0) {
                add_move_to_data(move_info,
                        create_move_string(from_x, from_y, to_x, to_y,
                                (char) 0));
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

/*
 * Stores all moves given a rocks position, the rocks color, and a valid board position in move_info
 * Returns 0 if failed, otherwise 1. If a error occured, some valid moves might still be stored.
 */
char store_all_moves_of_knight(char copy_board[8][8], char from_x, char from_y,
        MOVE_DATA* move_info, char color) {
    char no_error = 1;
    char dx;
    char dy;
    char* p1 = &dx;
    char* p2 = &dy;

    //Compressed code using pointer arithmetic:
    for (char i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (*p1 = -2; *p1 < 3; *p1 = *p1 + 4) {
            for (*p2 = -1; *p2 < 2; *p2 = *p2 + 2) {
                char to_x = from_x + dx;
                char to_y = from_y + dy;
                if (0 <= to_x & to_x < 8 & 0 <= to_y & to_y < 8) {
                    no_error = add_move_if_unused_by_equal_color(copy_board,
                            from_x, from_y, move_info, color, to_x, to_y);
                    if (!no_error)
                        return no_error;
                }
            }
        }
        p1 = &dy;
        p2 = &dx;
    }
    return no_error;
}

/*
 * Stores all moves given a rocks position, the rocks color, and a valid board position in move_info
 * Returns 0 if failed, otherwise 1. If a error occured, some valid moves might still be stored.
 */
char store_all_moves_of_rock(char copy_board[8][8], char from_x, char from_y,
        MOVE_DATA* move_info, char color) {
    //Vertikal
    //Up
    char no_error = 1;
    for (char dy = 1; from_y + dy < 8; dy++) {
        char temp_field = copy_board[(int) from_y + dy][(int) from_x];
        if (temp_field == 0) {
            no_error = add_move_to_data(move_info,
                    create_move_string(from_x, from_y, from_x, from_y + dy,
                            (char) 0));
            if (!no_error) {
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            if ((!color & (temp_field > 0)) || (color & !(temp_field > 0))) {
                no_error = add_move_to_data(move_info,
                        create_move_string(from_x, from_y, from_x, from_y + dy,
                                (char) 0));
            }
            if (!no_error) {
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    //Down
    for (char dy = -1; from_y + dy >= 0; dy--) {
        char temp_field = copy_board[(int) from_y + dy][(int) from_x];
        if (temp_field == 0) {
            no_error = add_move_to_data(move_info,
                    create_move_string(from_x, from_y, from_x, from_y + dy,
                            (char) 0));
            if (!no_error) {
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            if ((!color & (temp_field > 0)) || (color & !(temp_field > 0))) {
                no_error = add_move_to_data(move_info,
                        create_move_string(from_x, from_y, from_x, from_y + dy,
                                (char) 0));
            }
            if (!no_error) {
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    //Horizontal
    //Right
    for (char dx = 1; from_x + dx < 8; dx++) {
        char temp_field = copy_board[(int) from_y][(int) from_x + dx];
        if (temp_field == 0) {
            no_error = add_move_to_data(move_info,
                    create_move_string(from_x, from_y, from_x + dx, from_y,
                            (char) 0));
            if (!no_error) {
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            if ((!color & (temp_field > 0)) || (color & !(temp_field > 0))) {
                add_move_to_data(move_info,
                        create_move_string(from_x, from_y, from_x + dx, from_y,
                                (char) 0));
            }
            if (!no_error) {
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    //Left
    for (char dx = -1; from_x + dx >= 0; dx--) {
        char temp_field = copy_board[(int) from_y][(int) from_x + dx];
        if (temp_field == 0) {
            no_error = add_move_to_data(move_info,
                    create_move_string(from_x, from_y, from_x + dx, from_y,
                            (char) 0));
            if (!no_error) {
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            if ((!color & (temp_field > 0)) || (color & !(temp_field > 0))) {
                no_error = add_move_to_data(move_info,
                        create_move_string(from_x, from_y, from_x + dx, from_y,
                                (char) 0));

            }
            if (!no_error) {
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

/*
 * Stores all moves given a bishops position, the bishops color, and a valid board position in move_info
 * Returns 0 if failed, otherwise 1. If a error occured, some valid moves might still be stored.
 */
char store_all_moves_of_bishop(char copy_board[8][8], char from_x, char from_y,
        MOVE_DATA* move_info, char color) {
    char no_error = generate_all_moves_of_bishops_direction(copy_board, from_x,
            from_y, move_info, color, -1, -1);
    if (!no_error)
        return no_error;
    no_error = generate_all_moves_of_bishops_direction(copy_board, from_x,
            from_y, move_info, color, -1, 1);
    if (!no_error)
        return no_error;
    no_error = generate_all_moves_of_bishops_direction(copy_board, from_x,
            from_y, move_info, color, 1, -1);
    if (!no_error)
        return no_error;
    no_error = generate_all_moves_of_bishops_direction(copy_board, from_x,
            from_y, move_info, color, 1, 1);
    return no_error;
}

/*
 * Stores all moves given a queens position, the queens color, and a valid board position in move_info
 * Returns 0 if failed, otherwise 1. If a error occured, some valid moves might still be stored.
 */
char store_all_moves_of_queen(char copy_board[8][8], char from_x, char from_y,
        MOVE_DATA* move_info, char color) {
    char no_error = store_all_moves_of_rock(copy_board, from_x, from_y,
            move_info, color);
    if (!no_error)
        return no_error;
    no_error = store_all_moves_of_bishop(copy_board, from_x, from_y, move_info,
            color);
    return no_error;
}

/*
 * Stores all moves given a queens position, the queens color, and a valid board position in move_info
 * Returns 0 if failed, otherwise 1. If a error occured, some valid moves might still be stored.
 */
char store_all_moves_of_king(char copy_board[8][8], char from_x, char from_y,
        MOVE_DATA* move_info, char color) {
    char no_error;
    for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int k = -1; k < 2; k++) {
            char to_x = from_x + k;
            char to_y = from_y + i;
            if (0 <= to_x & to_x < 8 & 0 <= to_y & to_y < 8) {
                no_error = add_move_if_unused_by_equal_color(copy_board, from_x,
                        from_y, move_info, color, to_x, to_y);
                if (!no_error)
                    return no_error;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

/*
 * Returns all moves given a Board-State, including a legal board position. For illegal positions the
 * behaviour is undefined. However, it is allowed to pass a position, where the color to move is checked.
 */
MOVE_DATA return_all_moves(BOARD_STATE* plegal_board_state,
        char ignore_check) {
    MOVE_DATA move_data;
    move_data.array_size = MOVE_ARRAY_SIZE_BY_INIT;
    move_data.used_array_size = 0;
    move_data.moves = (char**) malloc(move_data.array_size * sizeof(char*));
    char copy_board[8][8];
    memcpy(copy_board, (plegal_board_state->board), sizeof(copy_board));
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_LEN; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < BOARD_LEN; k++) {
            char piece = copy_board[i][k];
            char color = piece > 0 ? 1 : -1;
            if (color != plegal_board_state->to_move) {
                continue;
            }
            switch (piece * color) {
            char c;
        case free_piece:
            continue;
        case pawn:
            c = store_all_moves_of_pawn(copy_board, k, i, &move_data, color);
            if (!c) {
                perror("OutOfMemoryException.");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            continue;
        case knight:
            c = store_all_moves_of_knight(copy_board, k, i, &move_data, color);
            if (!c) {
                perror("OutOfMemoryException.");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            continue;
        case bishop:
            c = store_all_moves_of_bishop(copy_board, k, i, &move_data, color);
            if (!c) {
                perror("OutOfMemoryException.");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            continue;
        case rock:
            ; //this is an empty statement since a label is not allowed before a declaration
            c = store_all_moves_of_rock(copy_board, k, i, &move_data, color);
            if (!c) {
                perror("OutOfMemoryException.");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            continue;
        case queen:
            c = store_all_moves_of_queen(copy_board, k, i, &move_data, color);
            if (!c) {
                perror("OutOfMemoryException.");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            continue;
        case king:
            c = store_all_moves_of_king(copy_board, k, i, &move_data, color);
            if (!c) {
                perror("OutOfMemoryException.");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            continue;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Unknown piece: %c on the board\nError.", piece);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

            }
        }
    }
    return move_data;
}

/*Merges to_be_added into to dest.
 * If successful, to_be_added moves will be freed.
 * Returns 1, if successful
 * Returns 0, OutOfMemoryException
 */
char merge(MOVE_DATA* dest, MOVE_DATA* to_be_merged) {
    void* c;
    if (dest->array_size
            < dest->used_array_size + to_be_merged->used_array_size) {
        c = realloc(dest->moves,
                (dest->used_array_size + to_be_merged->used_array_size)
                        * sizeof(char*));
        if (!c) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            dest->moves = (char**) c;
        }
        dest->array_size = dest->used_array_size
                + to_be_merged->used_array_size;
    }
    c = memcpy((dest->moves) + dest->used_array_size, to_be_merged->moves,
            to_be_merged->used_array_size);
    if (!c) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

/* Adds a move string to a MOVE_DATA
 * If there is no more space left, space of the MOVE_DATA will be doubled.
 * Returns 1, if successful
 * Returns 0, OutOfMemoryException
 */
char add_move_to_data(MOVE_DATA* move_info, char* move) {
    if (move_info->array_size == move_info->used_array_size) {
        char** p = realloc(move_info->moves,
                2 * (move_info->array_size) * sizeof(char*));
        move_info->array_size = 2 * (move_info->array_size);
        if (!p) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            move_info->moves = (char**) p;
        }
    }
    move_info->moves[move_info->used_array_size++] = move;
    return 1;
}

char generate_all_moves_of_bishops_direction(char copy_board[8][8], char from_x,
        char from_y, MOVE_DATA* move_info, char color, char dhorizontal,
        char dvertical) {
    char n = 1;
    char to_x;
    char to_y;
    char no_error = 1;
    while (((to_x = dhorizontal * n + from_x) < 8 & (to_x >= 0))
            & (((to_y = dvertical * n + from_y) < 8) & (to_y >= 0))) {
        if (copy_board[(int) to_y][(int) to_x] == 0) {
            no_error = add_move_to_data(move_info,
                    create_move_string(from_x, from_y, to_x, to_y, (char) 0));
        } else {
            if (color * copy_board[(int) to_y][(int) to_x] < 0) {
                no_error = add_move_to_data(move_info,
                        create_move_string(from_x, from_y, to_x, to_y,
                                (char) 0));
            }
            break;
        }
        n++;
    }
    return no_error;
}

//Returns 1 if successful, else 0
/*
 * NOTE THIS FUNCTION IS NOT CHECKING IF THE MOVE IS LEGAL. IT IS ONLY LOOKING IF THE FIELD IS USED BY ANOTHER
 * PIECE OF EQUAL COLOR AND THEN ADDS THE MOVE OR NOT. IN BOTH CASES 1 WILL BE RETURNED.
 */
char add_move_if_unused_by_equal_color(char copy_board[8][8], char from_x,
        char from_y, MOVE_DATA* move_info, char color, char to_x, char to_y) {
    if (copy_board[to_y][to_x] * color <= 0) {
        char no_error = add_move_to_data(move_info,
                create_move_string(from_x, from_y, to_x, to_y, (char) 0));
        return no_error;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This is the header-file:

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H

#define BOARD_LEN 8
#define MOVE_ARRAY_SIZE_BY_INIT 20

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct  {
    char board[8][8];
    char to_move;
    char pieces_moved[6];
} BOARD_STATE;

typedef struct {
    char** moves;
    size_t array_size;
    size_t used_array_size;
} MOVE_DATA;

char** return_all_moves(BOARD_STATE* pstate);
MOVE_DATA return_all_legal_moves(BOARD_STATE* pstate, char ignore_check);
char board_is_legal(BOARD_STATE* pstate);

char store_all_moves_of_pawn(char copy_board[8][8], char from_x, char from_y, MOVE_DATA* move_info, char color);
char store_all_moves_of_bishop(char copy_board[8][8], char from_x, char from_y, MOVE_DATA* move_info, char color);
char store_all_moves_of_rock(char copy_board[8][8], char from_x, char from_y, MOVE_DATA* move_info, char color);
char store_all_moves_of_queen(char copy_board[8][8], char from_x, char from_y, MOVE_DATA* move_info, char color);
char store_all_moves_of_king(char copy_board[8][8], char from_x, char from_y, MOVE_DATA* move_info, char color);

char add_move_to_data(MOVE_DATA* move_info, char* move);
char merge(MOVE_DATA* dest, MOVE_DATA* to_be_merged);
char generate_all_moves_of_bishops_direction(char copy_board[8][8], char from_x, char from_y,
        MOVE_DATA* move_info, char color, char dhorizontal, char dvertical);
char add_move_if_unused_by_equal_color(char copy_board[8][8], char from_x, char from_y, MOVE_DATA* move_info, char color,
        char to_x, char to_y);

#endif
```

1. I am searching for a general advice for a better desgin of the
   engine.
2. I am not looking for any optimizations yet.
3. I would also love your comments about readability.

Comment: You have a lot of [primitive obsession](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession). Make a lot more data types, and replace all these raw types being passed around everywhere. I see a dire need for at least `Board`, `Point`, `TeamColor` (an enum, iffy on the name), and possibly quite a few more.

Comment: "which accomplishes the generation of all (yet unvalidated) moves" That's a lot of moves. Did you mean all moves possible in one turn instead?

Comment: It's not enough for an answer, but I think you copied and pasted your comment from the rook function on to the knight one and forgot to change 'rook' to 'knight'.

Comment: @Mast Yes, I thought this was kinda obvious. I will change it :)

Comment: @JohnGowers Exactly, thanky you!

Comment: @Alexander Could you further explain the phenomenon? What you would do exactly? I fear that structure hugely slow down the computation.

Comment: @TVSuchty First let me introduce some terminology. "Strong" types are types whose set of "valid" values (in the business sense) are as close to the set of possible values. For example, using a `bool` to model `true` and `false` makes it very strong type. All of it possible values are legal. On the other hand, using a string, `int`, or `char` to model a boolean (as `"true"`/`"false"`, `1`/`0`, `'t'`/`'f'`) would make them very weak types. Because what happens if you have `"foo"`, `2`, `'Z'`? As far as C is concerned, all those are valid strings/ints/chars, respectively. But if your logic is...

Comment: ...relying on them to model bools, and each type has only 2 valid values, then you have a lot of *possible* but *logically illegal* values. That's an opportunity for a bug. Now everywhere you use (for example), a char to model a boolean, you need to ensure that the char is only `t`, `f` or otherwise handle the error case when it's something else. If you used a strong type (boolean, in this example), *the error case is simply not possible*, so there's no validation necessary. If anything this *speeds* things up (less checks = less branches)...

Comment: ... It also means you can't forget to check for illegal values (as there are none), which reduces bugs. In your example, you're using `char` to model the state of squares on the board, rather than something like an `enum SquareColor`. Furthermore, your use of separate x/y params (like `char from_x, char from_y`) is not only annoying (more typing), it's also more error prone. Everytim you want to forward that point to another function call, you have to fill in both `from_x` and `from_y`. If you copy/paste, you might accidentally paste `from_x` twice, causing a frustrating to debug logic error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96916/discussion-between-alexander-and-tvsuchty).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### `return` type

`char` should only be user for characters, as it's name says.  `unsigned char` for characters or for aliasing other types.  For everything else, use anything else.

If you want `(u)int8_t`, use `<stdint.h>`, and if you don't have that header, feel free to write your own `typedef` (enclosed in an `#if`).

But for error codes, the best is to use good old `int`.  Everybody uses `int` for error codes, so you won't mess with their brains when they wonder why you did use `char` :)

---

### Function return values and names (source: [Linux Kernel Coding Style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html#function-return-values-and-names))

Functions can return values of many different kinds, and one of the most common is a value indicating whether the function succeeded or failed. Such a value can be represented as an error-code integer (-Exxx = failure, 0 = success) or a succeeded boolean (0 = failure, non-zero = success).

Mixing up these two sorts of representations is a fertile source of difficult-to-find bugs. If the C language included a strong distinction between integers and booleans then the compiler would find these mistakes for us... but it doesn’t. To help prevent such bugs, always follow this convention:

```
If the name of a function is an action or an
 imperative command, the function should
 return an error-code integer. If the name is a
 predicate, the function should return a
 "succeeded" boolean.
```

For example, `add work` is a command, and the `add_work()` function returns 0 for success or `-EBUSY` for failure. In the same way, `PCI device present` is a predicate, and the `pci_dev_present()` function returns `true` if it succeeds in finding a matching device or `false` if it doesn’t.

---

### `no_error`

The variable `no_error` is misleading: it can hold an error code.  Probably the origin of the name was the inverted error return codes.  With non-zero error codes better names are: `error` or `status`.

---

### `copy_board`

The name of the parameter `copy_board` is misleading, given that it's not a copy, but a pointer to the original board.

---

### function names short

For making function names shorter, you can omit prepositions in them (when they are obvious).  For example, `store_all_moves_of_pawn()` -> `store_moves_pawn()`

---

### `#pragma once`

Although it has its own problems (only if your build configuration is completely broken, actually), it is less error-prone than typical `#ifndef`&`#define` include guards.

It's not standard, but most compilers accept it.

Just write this line at the beginning of the header:

```
#pragma once
```

[#pragma once vs include guards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1143936/6872717)

---

### Names and Order of Includes (source: [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Names_and_Order_of_Includes))

Use standard order for readability and to avoid hidden dependencies: Related header, C library, C++ library, other libraries' .h, your project's .h.

All of a project's header files should be listed as descendants of the project's source directory without use of UNIX directory shortcuts `.` (the current directory) or `..` (the parent directory). For example, `google-awesome-project/src/base/logging.h` should be included as:

```
#include "base/logging.h"
```

In `dir/foo.cc` or `dir/foo_test.cc`, whose main purpose is to implement or test the stuff in `dir2/foo2.h`, order your includes as follows:

dir2/foo2.h.

A blank line

C system files.

C++ system files.

A blank line

Other libraries' .h files.

Your project's .h files.

Note that any adjacent blank lines should be collapsed.

With the preferred ordering, if `dir2/foo2.h` omits any necessary includes, the build of `dir/foo.cc` or `dir/foo_test.cc` will break. Thus, this rule ensures that build breaks show up first for the people working on these files, not for innocent people in other packages.

`dir/foo.cc` and `dir2/foo2.h` are usually in the same directory (e.g. `base/basictypes_test.cc` and `base/basictypes.h`), but may sometimes be in different directories too.

Within each section the includes should be ordered alphabetically.

- In your case this would mean this order of includes:

```
#include "chess.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "odinutilities.h"
```

---

### unnecessary casts

Most (if not all) the casts you use are unnecessary.  Casts usually lead to bugs, remove them all if there's not a good reason for them to be.

---

### `ptrdiff_t`

The proper type for pointer arithmetics is `ptrdiff_t`, not `char` nor `int`.

Variables such as `to_y` should be declared of this type.

You will need `#include <stddef.h>`

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer!
I thought a processor will need less time adding chars instead of integers? Is this true?
If I typedef it, would not I use char anyway just by an alias?

Comment: @TVSuchty No, it isn't true (unless you have an 8-bit processor ;-)

Comment: @TVSuchty If you did the typedef, you would be using `char`. Actually even if not, because `<stdint.h>` actually does the same `typedef`. But the main problem is not with `char` but with readability (there's another problem with `char`, which isn't guaranteed to be `signed`, but it's not important in this case).

Comment: Guess, I have not :-)

Comment: @TVSuchty In C the `int` and `unsigned int` type will usually be the word size of the processor so all the native operations for the processor will run faster with int. char and short might be used in arrays where memory is tight.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Still, I would advise against `int` if speed is a concern: in 64 bit processors `int` is still 32 bits (usually). Better use explicit `(u)int_fastN_t` types from `<stdint.h>` for that purpose. However, for error codes, `int` will probably be as fast as possible, and very clear.

Comment: #pragma once - It isn't part of the standard, I prefer the #ifndef FILE_MACRO.which will always work and makes it more portable. Why do you think it is safer?

Comment: @pacmaninbw That's why I put the link. But if the compiler accepts it (most of them, since a decade ago), it's very valid. And when you forget to change the FILE_MACRO_H name after copy&paste (it happened to me more than once), it's a pain in the ass until you find it. #pragma doesn't have that problem. The link provides all this info and discussion, and anyone is of course free to use whatever, and I just pointed to the info just in case he didn't know :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the effort you put in!!!

Comment: @CacahueteFrito It might be better to create your answers in a text editor on your computer and then post it when the answer is complete rather than all the edits. That is what I do.

Comment: This is totally bike shedding, but I disagree on the suggestion to change `store_all_moves_of_pawn()` to `store_moves_pawn()`. Perhaps `store_pawn_moves()` is fine, but my personal fave is `store_all_pawn_moves`. I would recommend a more expressive approach. Keystrokes are free, and monitors are giant, there's really no need to be pinched on character count.

Answer (score 4):

First, interesting code!

I agree with most of what @CacahueteFrito wrote in his review except for the `#pragma once` item. The method you are using is more portable. I sometimes use `#pragma once` when the editor defaults to it on windows (Visual Studio), but not for C++.

I will primarily address style.

**Code Consistency**
The code is consistently indented, which is great, but the use of braces (`{` and `}`) in if statements is inconsistent. There are many places where braces are used around a single statement, but there are many places where braces aren't used around a single statement. It is more readable and maintainable when the code is consistent. Braces around a single statement are a good practice because quite often a new line of code needs to be inserted during maintenance.

**Always Test the Return Value of Memory Allocation Functions**
In most of the cases where memory is allocated the code is testing the return value, however, in the function `MOVE_DATA return_all_moves(BOARD_STATE* plegal_board_state, char ignore_check)` there is a call to `malloc(size_t size)` that is not tested. The function `malloc()` may also return NULL if there is not enough memory.

It might be better if the code was

```
char **tmp = malloc(move_data.array_size * sizeof(*p));
if (tmp) {
    move_data.moves = tmp;
}
else {
    // needs to be defined
}
```

because only the type of tmp needs to change if the type of `move_data.moves` is changed. This would be true for all the memory allocation performed in the program.

**Casting Malloc**
In modern C the functions `malloc()`, `calloc()` and `realloc()` return `void *`. It is not necessary to cast the memory returned by these statement to the proper type.

**Readability**
The code would be easier to read if there were some blank lines between blocks of code, such as after variable declarations at the top of the function, after a `if then else` block, after each of the cases in the switch statement.

**Function Complexity**
The function `char store_all_moves_of_rock(char copy_board[8][8], char from_x, char from_y, MOVE_DATA* move_info, char color)` is very complex and could be broken up into at least 4 sub functions, `up`, `down`, `left` and `right`. This function is probably misnamed, I believe is should be `all_moves_of_rook` rather than rock.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your critique! Glad you liked it. I will go for it!

Comment: Lol, I never noticed the difference between rock and rook. Thanks for educating me in English :P

Comment: Just a note that on many 64 bit systems (at least Linux and Mac I think, not sure of Windows), with sane environment settings, any reasonable use of `malloc` will never return NULL. Program(s) will start being killed if system runs out of memory and swap. A reasonable program will not run out of its own 64 bit virtual address space. It's still good to check it of course, but it's not worth putting much effort into handling it gracefully (just `abort()` or something).

Comment: @hyde and if it is an embedded processor that doesn't have all that much memory?

Comment: @pacmaninbw In that case you should really consider if you want to use a real operating system (such as embedded Linux), and research how you can configure and control `malloc` behavior (such as make it return NULL reliably, if your application is such that you can actually do something useful about it).